# Xamarin iOS deadlock on WKWebView CanPerform

Tags: ios, xamarin, wkwebview, deadlock

My problem is this:
Before returning true or false from CanPerform, I need to check some value from js, and only after that I can return.
This is my code:

```
public class CustomWKWebView : WKWebView
    {
        private const string SelectorOne = "One:";

        private const string SelectorTwo = "Two:";

        public CustomWKWebView(CGRect frame, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration) : base(frame, configuration)
        {
            _menu = UIMenuController.SharedMenuController;

            _menu.MenuItems = new[]
            {
            new UIMenuItem("One", new ObjCRuntime.Selector(SelectorOne)),
            new UIMenuItem("Two", new ObjCRuntime.Selector(SelectorTwo))
        }

        public override bool CanPerform(ObjCRuntime.Selector action, NSObject withSender)
        {
            /*this is a deadlock*/
            var checkValue = EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"window.getStatus();").Result;
            if (checkValue)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I thank all in advance. And waiting for your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with below code, the `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` is a async method and you can await it:

```
public override bool CanPerform(ObjCRuntime.Selector action, NSObject withSender)
{

    NSObject obj = new NSObject();
    var checkValue = obj;
        
    /*this is a deadlock*/
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
    {
         checkValue = await EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"window.getStatus();");
    });
    
    // check value of checkValue here
    if (...)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In this case return will before value checked. I should wait for checking end before CanPerform will return value.

Comment: Then you can't await `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` method inside CanPerform. You should get  checkValue before your every action and then choose to perform or not.

Comment: My "window.getStatus();" based on window.getSelection(), and call of CanPerform in my case happen when I make long press on wkwebview. I think I don't have any places where I could  call   window.getSelection() (before CanPerform), because selection of html text will not make yet.

Comment: Can you check the value before the long press?

Comment: No, because wkwebview doesn't provide such an opportunity.

Comment: Well, not much idea about the question. What you need to find is a way to await the EvaluateJavaScriptAsync method and then return true or false.